# Basic BLE profile/service

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a basic question about Bluetooth Low Energy profile/services.
I am working on a simple application where I have a BLE microcontroller (ATSAMB11) that has to communicate some simple (temperature, battery level) data to an android app. I am new and confused about which BLE profile/services I should choose for my application. Indeed as I am new, I am looking into example codes of the device (ATSAMB11) as well as for android app. 
All these examples use some kind of profile/service that are different and dependent on the application. They are listed here https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services
I am not sure of which one should I choose for my application because this will define which example I should look into and adapt to my application. 
So far I tried some chat example codes but was not successful with it. I was able to discover and pair but not connecting or communicating. Furthermore, I have read somewhere that chat service for BLE is not even using low energy.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at the BLE spec you should be consulting the device spec - i.e Microchip's appropriate Data sheet for [ATSAMB11](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATSAMB11)

> The qualified Bluetooth Smart protocol stack is stored in dedicated
>   ROM, the firmware includes L2CAP service layer protocols, Security
>   Manager, Attribute protocol (ATT), Generic Attribute Profile (GATT),
>   and the Generic Access Profile (GAP). Additionally, application
>   profiles such as Proximity, Thermometer, Heart Rate, Blood Pressure,
>   and many others are supported and included in the protocol stack.

Hence as per the data sheet, these should work for you:-

> Health
>   Thermometer   org.bluetooth.service.health_thermometer    0x1809  Adopted
>   Heart Rate    org.bluetooth.service.heart_rate    0x180D  Adopted
>   Blood Pressure    org.bluetooth.service.blood_pressure    0x1810  Adopted

Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) tutorial in Android's developer site for sample code. Let me know if you face issues in connecting to `GATT` server on `ATSAMB11` after going through it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've used the android developer site as an example but I am blocking on connecting the two devices. Indeed, from my ATSAMB11 I got the logging message "fail characteristic discovery". 
When I look into the specification of any profile/service from here:
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications 
It looks like there is a discovery characteristic procedure but I don't know how to implement this discovery procedure in my android app.

Comment: Ow it seems that this came from de UUID, I changed it with the one that was used in Atmel Smart Connect App and it was able to connect. But then it disconnected.

Comment: UUID s are defined in the standard that corresponds to GATT services. Which ever UUID you are copying should be the right profile/service ATSAMB11 supports

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth SIG has defined, along with the BLE spec, a series of standard GATT services and characteristics. Unfortunately, these are very limited in number and in usage.

Most of the people building BLE product actually choose to build their own custom services and characteristics. Assuming the temperature you want to put in your device is not "health thermometer", I would create a custom service based on a 128bits UUID (for temperature) and use the standard battery service (for battery voltage).

Here is an example of building a custom service for the Nordic nRF5x series : https://www.novelbits.io/bluetooth-gatt-services-characteristics/